# Ways to create XMLHttpRequests

Tags: javascript, ajax

I just started learning ajax recently and Im researching ways of creating HttpRequests
These are the ways I have come up with so far:

```
function one() {
if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    alert('Other');
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    alert('windows');
}
return xhr;
}


function two() {
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        alert('Other');
    } else if (!window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhr = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        alert('windows');
    }
    return xhr;
}

function three() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        alert('Other');
    } else {
        xhr = new ActiveXObject();
        alert('windows');
    }
    return xhr;
}

function four() {
    try {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        alert('Other');
    } catch (e) {
        xhr = new ActiveXObject();
        alert('windows');
    }
    return xhr;
}
```

I would like to know more ways of creating the request. If anyone has any other methods of doing this please share them. Part of what I like about Javascript is there are many ways of accomplishing the same tasks and I like to explore all possible options.

Comment: "_Part of what I like about Javascript is there are many ways of accomplishing the same tasks_" - in this particular case that is a bug, not a feature.  The different ways you are seeing here are exposing _incompatibilities_ and are mutually exclusive.

Comment: I was talking about the need to use `new ActiveXObject` vs `new XMLHttpRequest` and the couple other methods that MSIE supports.  The four different functions you've shown are mostly just stylistic choices, although I suspect 3 and 4 won't actually work on old versions of MSIE.

Comment: stylistic choices is what Im looking for. I want to see other ways of writing the same code.

Comment: @Bondy my question isn't about compatibility or support, its just about seeing how other people accomplish the same task

Answer (score 1):

I generally defer to jQuery when looking for good ways to do things,

```
// Functions to create xhrs
function createStandardXHR() {
    try {
        return new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch( e ) {}
}

function createActiveXHR() {
    try {
        return new window.ActiveXObject( "Microsoft.XMLHTTP" );
    } catch( e ) {}
}

// Create the request object
// (This is still attached to ajaxSettings for backward compatibility)
jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr = window.ActiveXObject ?
    /* Microsoft failed to properly
     * implement the XMLHttpRequest in IE7 (can't request local files),
     * so we use the ActiveXObject when it is available
     * Additionally XMLHttpRequest can be disabled in IE7/IE8 so
     * we need a fallback.
     */
    function() {
        return !this.isLocal && createStandardXHR() || createActiveXHR();
    } :
    // For all other browsers, use the standard XMLHttpRequest object
    createStandardXHR;
```

[Source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax/xhr.js)

Answer (score 1):

```
function four() {
  try {
    return new XMLHttpRequest(); 
  } catch (e) // Catch ReferenceError
    return new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
}
```